# runtime error when trying to insert after a node has previously been removed in a BST

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

I get a runtime error when I try to insert a number after a number has been deleted previously from the binary search tree. I'm assuming that somewhere in the tree after a deletion, that there is a broken path, so when it goes to insert the error occurs. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong. I assume it would be in the remove function. Here are the insert and remove functions:

```
void BST::insert(int x)
{
    TreeNode * v = root;
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = new TreeNode(x);
        return;
    }
    if (x == v->key)
    {
        return;
    }
    while (x != v->key)
    {

        if (x < v->key)
        {
            if (v->left != NULL)
            {
                v = v->left;

            }
            else
            {
                v->left = new TreeNode(x);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (x > v->key)
        {
            if (v->right != NULL)
            {
                v = v->right;
            }
            else
            {
                v->right = new TreeNode(x);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void BST::remove(TreeNode * & v, int x)
{
    if (v == NULL)
        return;
    if (x < v->key)
    {
        remove(v->left, x);
    }
    if (x > v->key)
    {
        remove(v->right, x);
    }
    if (x == v->key)
    {
        if (v->left == NULL && v->right == NULL)
        {
            delete v;
            return;
        }
        if (v->left == NULL)
        {
            TreeNode *temp = v;
            v = v->right;
            delete temp;
        }
        if (v->right == NULL)
        {
            TreeNode * temp = v;
            v = v->left;
            delete temp;
        }
        if (v->left != NULL && v->right != NULL)
        {
            TreeNode * u = v->right;
            while (u->left != NULL)
            {
                u = u->left;
            }
            v->key = u->key;
            remove(u, u->key);          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code, and several ways to dereference an invalid pointer.

In `remove`, when you've found the matching key, if the node has no children you delete it but don't null out the pointer to the deleted node, leaving a dangling reference.

You have a couple of series of `if` statements, that should be `else if` instead.  If `v->left == NULL`, you change `v` to point to the `right` node, then you compare this new value's `right` with NULL and could end up removing multiple nodes.

Comment: I set v = NULL and added the else if statements and now it works. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.